# My new 6TB HDD will take 40h to full format on a 2.0 case.. should I abort and do a quick format?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, format

Just got a new 6TB Ironwolf Pro. I put it in a USB 2.0 case temporarily for some days (I'll install it as internal) and ran a low-level format without thinking much about it. Two hours later, it's 5%... so I estimate It'll reach 100% in 40h (all that time running at 53ºC/127ºF).

Questions: sould I abort, install it internally and run a quick format? Is it safe to abort? Will it take less to do a full low-level format if it's installed internally instead of the 2.0 case or it does not matter?

Thanks

Comment: If it's factory-new hard drive, then there's no data on it, so no benefit to running a full format. If someone else used it before or it's been on the shelf for a while, there's some benefit, like finding sectors that have gone bad.

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to abort and do a quick format.

Your biggest problem is USB 2.0 is approx 25mb/s so it will take a super long time to complete a full format.

For comparison, internal you usually get 100-150mb/s so it completes in approx 1/4 to 1/5 of the time.

Comment: I thought that was a HDD-job only, not related with the Pc it's connected to. That's why I did not mind the slow external case. Thanks!

Comment: Tell it to abort and then wait for it to do so. Don't just pull the plug on it. These days a LLF is almost never needed especially with a new disk, and should only be used by someone who knows what they are doing. Install it in your machine, create partitions, and quick format.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use it in your PC, I would just put it in there and do the format. You can choose to do a quick or full format.

> Quick Format

- A quick format on a volume removes files from the partition, but does not scan the disk for bad sectors.

> Full Format

- A quick format on a volume removes the files from the partition, and the hard disk is scanned for bad sectors. The scanning for bad sectors is what makes it take quite a bit longer.

What I suggest is doing a quick format. Then run the cmd command `chkdsk /f`. That will fix possible bad sectors. In my experience this is a more efficient way to setup a new disk. With it being a new drive, it's likely that there are no bad sectors.

Comment: My understanding is that decades ago, a full format included sector checking, but no longer.  That is all now handled by the hard drive's internal controller.  Software like chkdsk can force a check.  Otherwise, bad sectors are discovered during use via the error correcting code.  A full format includes zero filling the partition, but not verifying the writes.  See this earlier thread: https://superuser.com/questions/1142155/full-formatting-hdd-controllers-and-bad-sector-locking.